# np.take returns an array with an extra singular dimension

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to slice an array of, say, shape `(5, 10, 2)` along the `0-th` axis with an index set containing 3 elements. As a result I get an array of shape `(1, 3, 10, 2)`. What is the reason for adding a dummy dimension in this case? This seems like a poor design to me, because ordinary indexing using the braces syntax doesn't do that. `np.compress` has the correct behavior too.

Comment: Care to provide a code snippet demonstrating your troubles?

Comment: I think you just want `a[[1,2,3]]` .   take is for more sophisticated extractions, and have its own logic.

Comment: What's the `shape` of your `index set`?  (3,) or (1,3)?

Comment: if you don't want it 'squeeze' will remove it, otherwise the explanations below are reasonable

Answer (score 2):

In NumPy, the shape of a returned array, whether indexing or using `np.take`, is affected by the shape of the indices passed. So, for example, if you index a 1D array with a 2D array of indices, you will get a 2D result:

```
>>> x = np.array([9, 8, 7, 6, 5])
>>> i = np.array([[1, 3], [2, 4]])
>>> x[i]
array([[8, 6],
       [7, 5]])
```

This holds even for multi-dimensional arrays, except the trailing dimensions are added to the index shape:

```
>>> x = np.random.rand(5, 4, 3)
>>> x[i].shape
(2, 2, 4, 3)
```

So if you have an array of indices that is of shape `(1, 3)`, that shape will be "imprinted" on the results:

```
>>> x = np.random.rand(5, 10, 2)
>>> i = np.array([[1, 2, 3]])
>>> x[i].shape
(1, 3, 10, 2)
```

This is equivalent for `take` along an axis:

```
>>> x.take(i, axis=0).shape
(1, 3, 10, 2)
```

Your question doesn't include any code, but I suspect that when you copied and pasted the indices into `take`, you copied the extra pair of square brackets:

```
>>> x[[1, 2, 3]].shape
(3, 10, 2)
>>> x.take([[1, 2, 3]], axis=0).shape
(1, 3, 10, 2)
```

The shape of the index array matters, and that can be quite useful when structuring more complicated expressions with numpy.